# Cakephp find(list) issue

Tags: php, cakephp

when i am trying to fetch data from following query

```
$this->ZipCode->find('list',array(
                                'fields'=>array('ZipCode.id','ZipCode.city'),
                                                       'conditions'=>array('ZipCode.province_id'=>$province_id)
                                            ));
```

It works fine but when do something like this.

```
$this->ZipCode->find('list',array('fields'=>array('ZipCode.province_id','ZipCode.city'),
                                            'conditions'=>array('ZipCode.province_id'=>$province_id)
                                            ));
```

an empty array returns. is there any problem in my query.??

Comment: Check what query it is executing.

Comment: how to check it.?? i am new in  cakephp.

Comment: Use PHPStorm , do **`Proper`** debugging using Xdebug.

Comment: I am 1000 % sure `ZipCode.province_id` doesnt exist in your table, as there only this word different in your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->ZipCode->find('list',array(
    'fields'=>array('province_id','city'),
    'conditions'=>array('ZipCode.province_id'=>$province_id)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

considering provincde_id is `x` you want an array like `[x => a, x => b]` , how is that even possible? Check what are array if you want to know why that is not possible Or if you want to select all city use something like :

```
$this->ZipCode->find('list',array('fields'=>array('ZipCode.city','ZipCode.city'),
                                        'conditions'=>array('ZipCode.province_id'=>$province_id)
                                        ));
```